# how to remove slashes from any commands python telegrambot using aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

im new to python and now im working to telegram bot using aiogram, i want to make my commands without slashes "/" in front of my commands.

the code i use

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start", 'help'], commands_prefix='/')
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hello! I'm Humann!")

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"you said {message.text}?")

executor.start_polling(dp)
```

i dont know how to remove slashes, anybody help please. i'll apreciate it.
thanks

aiogram, fix telegram bot

Answer (score 0):

Im prob. not the best person to answer, as Iv never coded in Py, but
maybe you can look for how to escape special character, such as `/`.

I found this on W3:

> \    Signals a special sequence (can also be used to escape special
> characters)   "\d"

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Maybe `\d` could be helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly:

> You want to send text commands without slashes

you could simply filter messages by text for example, you send to bot

> **info**

```
@dp.message_handler(text='info')
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    # you can do something here if user sends text message: info
    await message.answer(f"You send: {message.text}")
```

bot will answer:

> **You send: info**

And this looks like command without slash

**!!! Remember to paste this before all other text-messages handlers, or if you paste it last - your message will go to echo function (because it filters all text messages.**

---

Aiogram has a lot of variables for commands (CommandStart, CommandSettings)? you should see all in [aiogram filters documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters.html#builtin-filters)

Commands is better when you set default_commands in bot and next you could see and use them all when you press menu button (in private chat with bot)